# CodeIgniter Has relationship between models

Tags: codeigniter

I've been googling on this issue for a quite while and still haven't found a satisfactory answer yet :(

It's a small web-based online game where a **player** will **have** a **game board** and a **resource board**.  What is the best way to include those two classes in the player class to create a has-relationship?

Is there a particular way to do it in CI? or just go with include()?

Comment: You can use a ORM mapping solution.  http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Frameworks

Comment: Ummm it says "It is designed to map your Database tables into easy to work with objects, fully aware of the relationships between each other."   but it's not really 'database tables' I'm dealing with. I'm just looking for a best way to include other classes without breaking CI rules.

Comment: Im not sure I understand.  If your dealing with models, you can just use CI loader to include them $this->load->model('user') to one another

Comment: Ohhh, i thought that was only used by controller classes... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### An alternative is dependancy Injection

```
class userModel extends CI_Model
{
      public function __construct(gameModel $gameModel)
      {
         var_dump($gameModel instanceof gameModel);
      }
}
```

-

```
class Controller extends CI_Controller
{
     public function method()
     {
         $this->load->model('gameModel');
         // load model with dependancy on gameModel
         // or vise-verse
         $this->load->model('userModel', new gameModel);
     }
}
```

-

Or like I mention in comments

```
class userModel extends CI_Model
{
    public function method()
    {
       $gameModel = $this->load->model('gameModel');
    }

    public function __get($object)
    {
       $instance =&get_instance();
       return $instance->$object;
    }
}
```